# Is usage of "with" prefix acceptable for filter methods that are specific(not generic)

Tags: coding-style, naming, code-quality, naming-standards, filtering

I am not a native english speaker so I have the following question related to naming I have a class that has generic filter method of type:

```
filter(Predicate predicate)
```

In the same class I have some more concrete filter methods of type:

`filter(EventName eventName)` or `filter(Datafield datafield)`

Is it acceptable to use the prefix "with" for a filtering method. I have mostly encountered it in builder patterns not in a filter type of chaining. Is it a nonsense from the point of the language - english also from the point of naming conventions?

Then the code will look like:

```
messages.withEventName(eventName).withDatafield(datafield).first()
```

Comment: I don't think we can offer a general answer here. It's highly dependent on the language, framework, application, organization, etc.

Comment: But it is not a total nonsense ? I am asking because english is not my language so I need to know if it is a total nonsense or it is used sometimes for filtering ?

Comment: I think `where` might be more common

Comment: `with` is somewhat ambiguous, as you already noted (builder pattern). `where` is used in SQL and might be understood immediately by developers. A grammatically sound alternative for your specific examples would be `having`.

Answer (score 2):

"with" is grammatically correct, but I would say that "where" is more commonly used for this kind of thing as it matches up with SQL, which might be being used in the datalayer

Comment: The term "where" is more common in .NET. Other languages might use "filter" or "reject". This is definitely not standardized across tech stacks.

Answer (score 0):

Is the DSL (domain specific language) developed with among others the intent to support improving english knowledge of the developers using it? Then it should keenly follow english grammar. If the DSL is going to be used, besides developers, through reflective programming a prefix could be handy, it doesn't really count what it is.

The intention of the DSL sets the direction, that for example could be:

```
messages.named(eventName).dated(datafield).first()
```

if that's what's needed.